# What happen in background when we press kill -3 in Linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, kill

What happens when we issue `kill -3` in Linux console.

Can we issue `kill -3 %p` from Catalina pid.

Comment: [`$> man kill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill)

Comment: I believe the `kill -3` is used to take thread dump, not to terminate.

Comment: @Turing85 `man kill` doesn't help, really.

Comment: As stated in [unix java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html), if `-Xrs` option is not used then it is supposed to generate a thread dump. What happens in the backround is probably too complicated to answer.